# Media Queries being ignored by model

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm using LESS to compile my CSS. Below is a section of my CSS however the media query is being ignored. Trying to add different styles on the mobile.

```
#main-wrap header #hdr-nav nav {
  width: 60%;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
@media (max-width: 740px) {
  #main-wrap header #hdr-nav nav {
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

You can see the [live website](http://martynleeball.com/mps/) here, not too sure what is wrong with the query, seems to work fine on other websites.

Edit: 
[image]

Comment: on your website it works as expected (?)

Comment: if I inspect element it's not displaying the 90vw width

Comment: @Johannes turns out it's Chromes inspect element feature, it's scaling my website down :S Any idea why it would be doing this?

Comment: try to reset the page zoom (?)

Comment: Tried that, this is a strange issue, not had this before @Johannes see screenshot above

Comment: --> see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to insert the viewport meta tag on your page...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```